# Mocking a method on a property

Tags: c#, moq

I need to set the return value for a method returned by a property, basically I need to set what this does:

```
mockedObject.TheProperty.GetTheValues()
```

I just need it to return `Enumerable.Empty<MyType>`.

Comment: Typically what you'd do is create a mock or stub of whatever the property type is and then return that.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the class you have? By the look of it, you might have to mock the inner class first and then the mock the outer class and provider the inner Mock for the mocked Property...

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

For the purposes of demonstrating that the functionality exists assuming

```
public interface IFoo {
    IBar TheProperty { get; set; }
}

public interface IBar {
    IEnumerable<MyType> GetTheValues();
}

public class MyType { }
```

Moq allows for auto mocking hierarchies otherwise known as recursive mocks

```
[TestClass]
public class RecursiveMocksTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void Foo_Should_Recursive_Mock() {
        //Arrange
        IEnumerable<MyType> expected = Enumerable.Empty<MyType>();
        var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
        // auto-mocking hierarchies (a.k.a. recursive mocks)
        mock.Setup(_ => _.TheProperty.GetTheValues()).Returns(expected);

        var mockedObject = mock.Object;

        //Act
        IEnumerable<MyType> actual = mockedObject.TheProperty.GetTheValues();

        //Assert
        actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
    }
}
```

Note that at no point was `IBar` ever initialized or configured. The framework will auto mock that interface because of the setup shown above.

If however, more functionality is needed from an `IBar`, then a proper mock should be done and configured accordingly. There is also nothing stopping the use of configuring multiple `IBar` members via the `IFoo` mock.

Reference [Moq Quickstart: Properties](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#properties)

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have this:

```
public interface IA
{
    IEnumerable<MyType> TheProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MyType {}
```

Then here is how to mock it so when `TheProperty` is called, it returns and `IEnumerable.Empty<MyType>`:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeTest()
{
    /* Arrange */
    var iAMock = new Mock<IA>();
    iAMock.Setup(x => x.TheProperty).Returns(Enumerable.Empty<MyType>());

    /* Act */

    /* Assert */
}
```

Comment: I think the idea is that `TheProperty` is a type that has a `IEnumerable<MyType> GetTheValues` method.

Comment: @juharr I just wanted to show how to mock and return. That knowledge can now be used to mock and return `TheProperty` also. But yes you are correct.